# How do I export an array output of a CSV in ruby to html?

Tags: ruby, arrays

below is my ruby script

```
require "rubygems"
require 'csv'

a = Array.new
CSV.foreach("p34n234.csv") do |row|
    a << row
end

print a
```

What i want to do is now at the end I want to generate a html file and print array to it.

I hope i made sense.

Thanks

P.S I just want to show the array in a .html file. Nothing fancy here:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would be doing something like this...

```
print "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html><body>#{your_array}</body></html>\r\n"
```

Comment: yep makes sense. did with puts and a little different thout.